# Does gcc give worse/slower code using v* assembly instructions?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, icc

Consider this simple loop:

```
float f(float x[]) {
  float p = 1.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    p += x[i];
  return p;
}
```

If you compile it with -O2  -march=haswell in gcc you get:

```
    f:
            vmovss  xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
            lea     rax, [rdi+512]
    .L2:
            vaddss  xmm0, xmm0, DWORD PTR [rdi]
            add     rdi, 4
            cmp     rdi, rax
            jne     .L2
            ret
    .LC0:
            .long   1065353216
```

However, the Intel C Compiler gives:

```
f:
        xor       eax, eax                                      #3.3
        pxor      xmm0, xmm0                                    #2.11
        movaps    xmm7, xmm0                                    #2.11
        movaps    xmm6, xmm0                                    #2.11
        movaps    xmm5, xmm0                                    #2.11
        movaps    xmm4, xmm0                                    #2.11
        movaps    xmm3, xmm0                                    #2.11
        movaps    xmm2, xmm0                                    #2.11
        movaps    xmm1, xmm0                                    #2.11
..B1.2:                         # Preds ..B1.2 ..B1.1
        movups    xmm8, XMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax*4]                 #4.10
        movups    xmm9, XMMWORD PTR [16+rdi+rax*4]              #4.10
        movups    xmm10, XMMWORD PTR [32+rdi+rax*4]             #4.10
        movups    xmm11, XMMWORD PTR [48+rdi+rax*4]             #4.10
        movups    xmm12, XMMWORD PTR [64+rdi+rax*4]             #4.10
        movups    xmm13, XMMWORD PTR [80+rdi+rax*4]             #4.10
        movups    xmm14, XMMWORD PTR [96+rdi+rax*4]             #4.10
        movups    xmm15, XMMWORD PTR [112+rdi+rax*4]            #4.10
        addps     xmm0, xmm8                                    #4.5
        addps     xmm7, xmm9                                    #4.5
        addps     xmm6, xmm10                                   #4.5
        addps     xmm5, xmm11                                   #4.5
        addps     xmm4, xmm12                                   #4.5
        addps     xmm3, xmm13                                   #4.5
        addps     xmm2, xmm14                                   #4.5
        addps     xmm1, xmm15                                   #4.5
        add       rax, 32                                       #3.3
        cmp       rax, 128                                      #3.3
        jb        ..B1.2        # Prob 99%                      #3.3
        addps     xmm0, xmm7                                    #2.11
        addps     xmm6, xmm5                                    #2.11
        addps     xmm4, xmm3                                    #2.11
        addps     xmm2, xmm1                                    #2.11
        addps     xmm0, xmm6                                    #2.11
        addps     xmm4, xmm2                                    #2.11
        addps     xmm0, xmm4                                    #2.11
        movaps    xmm1, xmm0                                    #2.11
        movhlps   xmm1, xmm0                                    #2.11
        addps     xmm0, xmm1                                    #2.11
        movaps    xmm2, xmm0                                    #2.11
        shufps    xmm2, xmm0, 245                               #2.11
        addss     xmm0, xmm2                                    #2.11
        addss     xmm0, DWORD PTR .L_2il0floatpacket.0[rip]     #2.11
        ret                                                     #5.10
.L_2il0floatpacket.0:
        .long   0x3f800000
```

If we ignore the loop unrolling, the most obvious difference is that gcc using vaddss and icc uses addss.

> Is there a performance difference between these two pieces of assembly
>   and which one is better (ignoring the loop unrolling)?

---

The v prefix comes from the [VEX coding scheme](http://VEX%20coding%20scheme). It seems you can get icc to use these instructions by added `-xavx` as part of the command line flags.  However, the question remains if there is any performance difference between the two sets of assembly in the question or if there is any advantage of one over the other.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Perhaps because it seems like you haven't done any research at all.

Comment: @fuz My research was to get the assembly in a readable format.  I don't know how to work out which assembly is better though.

Comment: I think people expect you to research why there are v... instructions and what the difference is (search for VEX).

Comment: @fuz Oh right. Yes I did look up VEX instructions but I couldn't work out if there was a performance difference or why gcc would prefer one and icc the other.

Comment: ICC probably uses legacy instructions because you didn't tell it to use AVX or because your version is too old.

Comment: @fuz Do you think the performance should be the same?

Comment: In this case probably yes. However, only a benchmark can remove any lingering doubt.

Comment: @fuz Which one do you suspect is faster?

Comment: I already answered that question.

Comment: @fuz I misread. Apologies.  I am tempted to delete this question.  What do you think?

Comment: Please don't. It's a fine question however, you should have done more research before resp. reference that research in your question so we know where to pick you up with an answer.

Comment: The difference is that gcc conforms to the ieee754 floating-point spec in this case and generates code that doesn't incorrectly treat `float` addition as associative. If you tell gcc to ignore the inaccuracy via `-ffast-math` or `-Ofast`, it will generate vectorized code too.

Comment: @EOF Thank you. Another downvote I see :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instructions with mnemonics prefixed `v` are VEX encoded instructions. The VEX encoding scheme allows for the encoding of every SSE instruction as well as the new AVX instructions and some other instructions. There is an almost 1:1 correspondence between legacy instructions and VEX encoded instructions with the following differences:

- VEX encoded SSE instructions implicitly zero out the high 128 bit of the `ymm` register corresponding to the `xmm` register operand used in the instruction. This avoids a costly partial register update if a previous instruction left data in these bits.
- The VEX encoding scheme allows instructions to have an additional output operand instead of overwriting one of the input operands. This reduces register pressure and allows the compiler to generate less data moves, slightly increasing performance.
- AVX instructions can only be encoded with a VEX prefix because the 256 bit data width cannot be communicated by any other mean.